# Python logging loosing most of messages at midnight log file switch

Tags: python, logging

My logging creates 2 files, one at DEBUG level and another at WARNING level, and at midnight UTC time a new file is created. Server is Litespeed/Cloudlinux with Python 3.9.

It worked very well for more than a month, then started to loose most of messages at the time to create a new file, at midnight. Seems at midnight the current log file `mywebsite_UTC_time__DEBUG.log` is correctly renamed to `mywebsite_UTC_time__DEBUG.log.2022-08-10__00_00_00.log`, and a new file `mywebsite_UTC_time__DEBUG.log` is created, but for some unknown reason (because website traffic is rising and more messages are logged?), around 30 to 60 minutes later, this process is repeated, overwriting the correct `mywebsite_UTC_time__DEBUG.log.2022-08-10__00_00_00.log` that ends-up with only the messages logged in the first 30 to 60 minutes of the following day.

This is the code of my logging system:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers as handlers
import time

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


logging.Formatter.converter = time.gmtime
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(name)-30s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s [%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d]')

logHandler = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('logs_app/mywebsite_UTC_time__DEBUG.log',
                                               encoding='utf-8',
                                               when='midnight',
                                               interval=1,
                                               backupCount=0,
                                               utc=True)
logHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logHandler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d__%H_%M_%S.log"
logHandler.encoding = 'utf-8'


errorLogHandler = handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler('logs_app/mywebsite_UTC_time__WARNING.log',
                                                    encoding='utf-8',
                                                    when='midnight',
                                                    interval=1,
                                                    backupCount=0,
                                                    utc=True)
errorLogHandler.setLevel(logging.WARNING) 
errorLogHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
errorLogHandler.suffix = "%Y-%m-%d__%H_%M_%S.log"
errorLogHandler.encoding = 'utf-8'

logger.addHandler(logHandler)
logger.addHandler(errorLogHandler)
```

Any idea on what is wrong?

Comment: Re. your comment - it doesn't matter if you are explicitly using the `multiprocessing` module or not, it's still a multiprocess situation if you have e.g. multiple workers logging to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

If you could have multiple processes writing to the same log file (e.g. through Python worker processes) then you might get this type of issue. You should ensure that only one process writes to the log file, using the techniques described in the [Python logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes).

Comment: It is a web app with flask. May have Cloudlinux WSGI workers depending on how many users access simultaneously, but there is no multiprocessing implemented in my code. Now it is loosing the log files (DEBUG and WARNING) multiple times a day.